# How do you print out the value of a System::Classes::TWndMethod variable?

Tags: c++builder

If I have a variable that is of type `System::Classes::TWndMethod`, how can I print out the value with any of the `*printf` type functions using `%p`?

I tried casting to `(void*)` but the compiler failed with an internal error.

Basically, I have the `WndProc` of three `TEdit` fields that I'm overriding.  They can all be handled the same, so I wanted to see if they all use the same `WndProc` (for the callback to original routine), which I presume they would, but would like to check before actually doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print out a `TWndMethod` as-is using `%p`, because it is not a single pointer, it is actually a struct which holds 2 pointers.

If you want to print them out, cast the `TWndMethod` to [`System::TMethod`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) first:

> The TMethod type stores the Code and Data pointers for a method. This type can be used in a type cast of a method pointer to access the code and data parts of the method pointer.

Then you can print out its `Code` and `Data` fields as needed, where:

- the `Code` field points at the class method itself
- the `Data` field points at the object which is passed to the method's hidden `this` parameter.

For example:

```
TWndMethod wm = ...;
TMethod &m = reinterpret_cast<TMethod&>(wm);
printf("%p %p\n", m.Code, m.Data);
```